# how to enter a number in an input field with type ="number' using karate UI

Tags: karate, ui-automation

For automation I need to enter a value in to an input field as below using karate UI.
input type="number"  inputmode="numeric"

I tried

- input('*xpath of the field*',"7")

which resulted in below error:

org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: js eval failed twice:var e = document.evaluate("*xpath of the field*", document, null, 9, null).singleNodeValue; e.focus(); try { e.selectionStart = e.selectionEnd = e.value.length } catch(x) {}, error: [type: MAP, value: {type=object, subtype=error, className=SyntaxError, description=SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list, objectId=-19151743.2.4}]

- com.intuit.karate.driver.DevToolsDriver.evalInternal(DevToolsDriver.java:358)
- com.intuit.karate.driver.DevToolsDriver.eval(DevToolsDriver.java:322)
- com.intuit.karate.driver.DevToolsDriver.input(DevToolsDriver.java:636)

How this can be solved